# Multiple Joins in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to JOIN multiple tables to the same value in a table. So I have the table ActivityPartyBase and it has a column PartyId. I want to join COntactId in ContactBase table to PartyId and AccountId in AccountBase table to PartyId. This is the code I am using and it doesn't return anything. If I only join one it works. Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Appointment.ScheduledStart, ActivityPartyBase.ActivityId
   , Appointment.ActivityId AS Expr1, ActivityPartyBase.ScheduledStart AS Expr2
   , Appointment.Subject, ActivityPartyBase.PartyId, ContactBase.ContactId
   , ContactBase.FullName
FROM Appointment
INNER JOIN ActivityPartyBase
   ON Appointment.ActivityId = ActivityPartyBase.ActivityId
INNER JOIN AccountBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = AccountBase.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = ContactBase.ContactId
ORDER BY Appointment.ScheduledStart DESC
```

Comment: Unrelated to functionality, but readability would probably be better with aliases for those long table names.

Comment: When you say `if I only join one it works` which join works? Is there data for the other joins?

Comment: If I only join ContactBase it works and if I only join AccountBase it works. Just doesn't work if I join both of them.

Comment: If you only join ContactBase to what? Join AccountBase to what?

Comment: to ActivityPartyBase.PartyId. Join both to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner joins are filtering out results because there is no corresponding record on the joined table. I've always found the easiest way to debug is to "Select *" and use all LEFT JOINs. This will show you everything in your tables that relates to your main table; you should be able to look at your data and figure out what table is missing a record easily at that point.

To confirm that this is just a naming convention mismatch,

```
INNER JOIN AccountBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = AccountBase.AccountId
```

Are PartyID and AccountId the PK/FK?

Comment: Yea it's just how CRM 2011 names them. But those are how they match up to get the names of meeting attendees.

Answer (score 3):

Given this...

```
FROM Appointment 
   INNER JOIN ActivityPartyBase ON Appointment.ActivityId = ActivityPartyBase.ActivityId 
   INNER JOIN AccountBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = AccountBase.AccountId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = ContactBase.ContactId
```

... you state this works (?) ...

```
FROM Appointment 
   INNER JOIN ActivityPartyBase ON Appointment.ActivityId = ActivityPartyBase.ActivityId 
   /* INNER JOIN AccountBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = AccountBase.AccountId */
   /* LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactBase ON ActivityPartyBase.PartyId = ContactBase.ContactId */
```

Since the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` won't explicitly cause no results, that won't be your problem.  Since the `INNER JOIN` will cause what you're seeing, we can only deduce that the join condition is incorrect.

In other words, `ActivityPartyBase.PartyId` is not equal to `AccountBase.AccountID`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is data in all three tables in the inner join?

Comment: Yup. They return data as long as I don't join both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing one of your INNER JOINs isn't picking up any data.  Start with all 3 joins, then take out one of the joins at a time see which one breaks it.  Then look at your join conditions and see which column isn't returning a record.

Answer (score 0):

SOunds to me as if the tables are mutually exclusive. If it is ione table it is not inthe other (poor design). Try left joins to both tables.